# Ubuntu on an Asus rog G751 JL

Tags: boot, ssd, asus

First of all, I'm a complete newbie regarding Ubuntu and Linux, but I really want to learn about them as much as I can. After some documentation, I realized that this OS may be the future's best :D

So, my problem is this: The laptop I mentioned in the title has a 120 GB SSD and 1024 GB HDD. I had Windows 10 installed on it before, on SSD, with data on HDD. I actually want to do the same thing with Ubuntu, to put the "/" volume on SSD and the "/home" one on HDD, but here comes the problem: If I install it on HDD, it will work normally (except for the `error parsing pcc subspaces from pcct` prompt at boot). However, if I install it on the SSD, it won't boot. I checked the BIOS and there is no option for my SSD as a boot loader (but again, Windows works fine this way).

So... Can you help me? Or give me a guide on installing Ubuntu on an Asus rog laptop? I heard I'm not the only one with the Rog - Linux problems... Please try to explain with lots of details, I want to learn as much as I can.

I want only Ubuntu, not a dual boot system.

Comment: First of all make sure you're booting (and installing) in UEFI mode.

Comment: Not sure how easy is dismounting the hard drive on your laptop, but did you tried to remove the 1TB hard drive to see if it boots properly? If you, you may try to swap both hard drive location inside your computer (if feasible, of course, it's impossible if you have a mSATA hard drive).

Comment: @olivierb2 How would they have `/home` in the HDD as intended with it disconnected? Plus, this is not the problem you think it is, it's something else.

Comment: okay, in that case, what kind of issue did you endure when your computer starts? Are you getting the grub boot loader, splash screen? Or stopping in the BIOS/EFI boot process?
edit: also find this guide, did you tried to follow it? https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?54342-Dual-booting-Windows-8-1-amp-Ubuntu-14-04-in-G751JT

Comment: The guide above is interesting but outdated in many parts: `nomodeset` is only required when the open source driver for Nvidia cards doesn't support the graphics properly. Newer Ubuntu releases shouldn't need it (but still you should install Nvidia drivers afterwards). There should be no need to add a PPA but if it is then it's NOT the one mentioned in the guide. Again, the most probable cause for it not booting when installed in the SSD is it being installed in Legacy mode.

Comment: @olivierb2 Well... the issue is a black screen that says I have to insert a boot drive or media (just like I didn't installed anything)

Comment: Ohhh, and another strange thing that I don't understand properly: I'm pretty sure I have BIOS , BUT when I had windows installed on the laptop, in the bios menu of boot loader, there was something like "[UEFI] name_of_SSD". I am not very sure why was that... I have NOTHING ELSE in the BIOS menu talking about UEFI, so I'm really not sure how to boot in the UEFI mode (If I actually have it...)

Comment: it's very difficult to says what is wrong in your setup, are you creating the partition setup manually during the install? Maybe you miss the important UEFI partition? You should have at least an small partition with file system named "EFI System" to mount point "/boot/efi" of 512Mbytes.